# Решение системы уравнений. Не работает программа

Tags: математика, if, matlab

Вопрос по матлабу:

Вот задание:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код:

```
function y = ff(x,a,b)
    if x<0
        y=b.*sin(a./x)
    else if x>5
          y=exp(x)+log(abs(x))
        else if (x>3) & (x<=5)
                y=x+(cos(a.*x)./(x.^2+1))
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Вызываю:

```
fplot('ff(x,3.9,4.6)',[-1 6]);
```

Вот что выдает:

```
    Warning: Error updating FunctionLine.

 The following error was reported evaluating the function
 in FunctionLine update: Output argument "y" (and maybe
 others) not assigned during call to "ff".
```

Что это означает и в чем может быть проблема?
И еще вопрос правильно ли я использую логическое И?

Примечание: если убрать последний if, оставив else *выражение*, то все прекрасно работает

```
function y = ff(x,a,b)
    if x<0
        y=b.*sin(a./x)
    else if x>5
          y=exp(x)+log(abs(x))
        else y=x+(cos(a.*x)./(x.^2+1))            
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: У вас небольшая, но неприятная проблема: что делать при 0 <= x <= 3? Вот программа и сходит с ума - причем очень внятно поясняет, в чем проблема.

Comment: Вообще, я думал, что там будет что-то типа разрыва?

Comment: Теперь понял, спасибо)